# In AS3 how XML Node value use as another node?

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

Suppose I have an XML

```
<xml>

<lang>en</lang>
<en>
    <text id="123">One Two Three</text>
    <text id="hello">Hello</text>
</en>

</xml>
```

the "en" tag is only if the lang value is "en".
If the value of lang is "de"

```
<lang>de</lang>
<de>
        <text id="123">One Two Three</text>
        <text id="hello">Hello</text>
</de>
```

How do I get this name dinamicaly in my actionscript 3 code.

Suppose I want to use

```
var xmlVal = new XML(... the above xml)
var lang = xmlVal.lang;
```

I can't use if (xmlVal.lang == "en") .. because the lang value can be any string. but there should be a child node in that name..!!

How do I get values from node "en or de or what ever.." ??

Comment: I'm not sure if the following works but, have you tried: `var langXml:* = xmlVal[xmlVal.lang];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested, but this should give you the general idea (that you can dynamically select using the "key"):

```
var xmlVal:XML = new XML(... the above xml);

var type:String = xmlVal.lang;

var result:XML = xmlVal[type];
```

Comment: while it's a bit more specific, you can also check for `if( xmlVal.en != undefined )`

Comment: 1. Type your variables. 2. Don't use constructors on top level classes (except for Vectors, and Arrays which have a set length).

Comment: @cwallenpoole: What do you mean by #2? Are you referring to `new XML(...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var lang:String = xmlVal.lang;
var strings:XMLList = xmlVal.elements(lang).text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more extensible and consistent ways to do this.

```
var xmlVal:XML = XML( /*above*/ );
// xmlVal.child("lang"); is a long-hand for xmlVal.lang, but more explicit
// it can also save you headache later in some corner cases.
var langs:XMLList = xmlVal.child("lang"); 
// if there is only one lang child, this will grab its' child text
// use toString to make sure you only grab the string pieces.
var langVal:String = langs[0].text().toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
var langValue:XMLList = xmlVal.child(langVal);
```

You're better off, though, if you can change it from:

```
...
<lang>en</lang>
<en>
```

to

```
...
<lang abbreviation="en"><text id="123">One Two Three</text>
    <text id="hello">Hello</text></lang>
```

Then you can call:

```
var xmlVal:XML = XML( /*above*/ );
var finalList:XMLList = xmlVal.child( "lang" ).( @abbreviation == "en" );
```